# Can an ISP block any outgoing mail port?

Tags: email, port

Can an ISP block any port they want? I know port 25 is frequently blocked, but can an ISP block other ports commonly used for outgoing mail?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, an ISP can block any port he wants as long as he has good/convincing reasons for this.

The question should always be what reasons that might be.

Comment: Thank you! We have been having problems with our customers receiving phishing emails, but the registrar refuses to help suspend the domain. We wanted to see if there was another way to prevent these emails from being sent (we have the phishing emails with headers as evidence). 

Have you heard of that kind of thing happening?

Comment: No sorry, didn‘t hear abouf it.